# Is there a need for the [haskell-arrows] tag?

Tags: discussion, status-declined, tags, burninate-request

I just came across the [haskell-arrows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/haskell-arrows) tag. It has 4 questions and 0 followers. My suggestion is to burninate it because it is way too specific, unclear in its usage and all in all useless.

Comment: Most questions about arrows in Haskell use the [`haskell`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/haskell) and [`arrows`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/arrows) tags. I say retag them to that. Similarly, questions about monads use `haskell` and `monads`, not `haskell-monads`.

Comment: -1 I don't see overly specific tags as a problem, it should be used for questions about the abstraction known as 'arrow' that is related to monads and applicatives, and it seems quite useful to an arrow expert who wants to be notified of or search for all questions about arrows. [tag:arrows] is *way* too ambiguous, and while arrows aren't limited to Haskell, [tag:haskell-arrows] seems to be the best tag to disambiguate the subject.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

"arrows" is such a generic term that I think it'd be better to retag [arrows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/arrows) to [haskell-arrows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/haskell-arrows) than vice-versa. Currently there are a lot of questions using [arrows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/arrows) for other more generic meanings of the term.

Alternatively something non-Haskell specific like "arrows-abstraction" might be more future proof in case some other language starts using them too.

[monads](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/monads) is different because the word only has one popular meaning.